# Customize Overall Health of Spring Boot Actuator Health Check

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

I'm setting up the health check for my spring application and as part of it I created a custom health indicator to check a downstream call's own health check. If it's down, the downstream call is marked as `DOWN`. Right now, the health check looks like the following

```
{
    "status" : "DOWN",
    "downstreamCall" : {
        "status" : "DOWN",
        "Error Code" : 1
     },
     .
     .
     .
     "diskSpace" : {
         "status" : "UP",
         "free" : 209047318528,
         "threshold" : 10485760
     }
}
```

So the `downstreamCall` is being marked as down, when it's down, as it should. However, when the `downstreamCall` is marked as down, I want the overall status to be marked as `DEGRADED`, as shown below.

```
{
    "status" : "DEGRADED",
    "downstreamCall" : {
        "status" : "DOWN",
        "Error Code" : 1
     },
     .
     .
     .
     "diskSpace" : {
         "status" : "UP",
         "free" : 209047318528,
         "threshold" : 10485760
     }
}
```

This is specifically for the downstreamCall. Any other part of the health check that is `DOWN` should still result in the overall status being `DOWN`. I've been looking through the Spring documentation as well as questions here but haven't found a way to achieve this.

Comment: You can not have DEGRADED status as it is not supported. You can have UP, DOWN, OUT_OF_SERVICE, UNKNOWN

Comment: So the overall status can never be DEGRADED? If I set the custom health indicator to DEGRADED then the overall status will be marked as DEGRADED as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear when it was added, but since at least SpringBoot 2 (and beyond) custom types are supported...

See also:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/production-ready-features.html

Add something such as the following to your `application.yml`:

```yaml
management.endpoint.health.status:
  order: fatal,down,out-of-service,jones,unknown,up
  http-mapping:
    up: 200
    jones: 410
    down: 200
    fatal: 500
    out-of-service: 503
```

Then, in a custom health component, you can do something like:

```java
Health.Builder jonser = Health.status("jones");
// Add more detail here if you'ld like.
return jonser.build();
```

This results in a health status body of something to the order of:

```json
{
    "status": "jones",
    "components": {
    // etc...
    }
}
```

NOTE: In my tests, if you skip the `order` part, the status will come out as `UNKNOWN`.